# The commutation relation of the Poincare algebra.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, mathematical-physics

In many quantum field theory textbooks, when looking for the Lie algebra of the Poincaré group,
$$[M^{\mu\nu}, M^{\rho\tau}]=i(g^{\mu\tau}M^{\nu\rho}+g^{\nu\rho}M^{\mu\tau}-g^{\mu\rho}M^{\nu\tau}-g^{\nu\tau}M^{\mu\rho})$$
$$[P^{\mu}, M^{\nu\rho}]=-i(g^{\mu\rho}P^{\nu}-g^{\mu\nu}P^{\tau})$$
$$[P^{\mu},P^{\nu}]=0$$
they use a particular unitary representation to check that these commutation relations hold under the unitary representation, and thereby declare that these algebraic relations hold in the general case.

Here I have two questions.

1. when checking the commutatiton relation of a Lie algebra, is it enough to take a particular representation and check the exchange relation for it?

I thought that when constructing a representation of a Lie algebra, the commutation relations between generators must be known in advance to construct the representation, but am I mistaken?

2. Is it possible to calculate the commutation relations between generators of a Lie algebra in such a way that does not depend on a particular representation is used?

Comment: Something is deeply wrong with the sources that you are reading since the Lie algebra of the Poincare group does not even have a faithful finite dimensional unitary representation. As for your questions: No for 1 and yes for 2.